# FILE MS-DOS Encoding C++

Tags: file, dos

How to write some text into a txt file with MS-DOS encoding ?
I'm using class FILE. May be I must use another class?

```
CString text;
 CString file_name;
 text = "My text must be in txt file in MS-DOS encoding.";
 file_name = "MyFile.txt";
 FILE *fp;
 fp = fopen(file_name, "w+");
 fprintf(fp, text + "\n");
 fclose(fp);
```

Comment: you set the locale, and thus the encoding, with the `imbue` method, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11646368/how-to-set-file-encoding-format-to-utf8-in-c , but I'm not really sure about what is the right locale for MS-DOS, it's a quite old encoding and I don't have a Windows machine right now, but I assume that you can try something with this method.

Comment: "MS-DOS encoding" is not well-defined. At particular points in time, a reasonable guess could be codepage 437 or 850, but it depends on where you are.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing special about MS-DOS encoding other than end-of-line is represented by a `\r\n` two character sequence. If you open the file in text mode as you have done then this should happen automatically.

Answer (score 0):

CharToOem (src, dst);
must be used to transform into MS-DOS encoding.